# Sinon.JS stub that resolves a promise returns "{}"

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have a Node.js function that returns a promise. I am using [Sinon.JS stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/) to resolve the promise. My console.log statements in the code show that the stub is working. However, what is returned is `{}` instead of what the Promise resolves to.

I reviewed these other SO posts, but neither were exactly the problem I am running into:

- [Sinon.JS stub a function that resolves a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712649/sinon-js-stub-a-function-that-resolves-a-promise)
- [When to reject/resolve a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293546/when-to-reject-resolve-a-promise)

Here is the function:

```
function publishMessage(pubsub, topicName, data) {   
  const topic = pubsub.topic(topicName);   
  const publisher = topic.publisher();

  return publisher.publish(data)
    .then((results) => {
      const messageId = results[0];
      return messageId;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error ', error);
      return error;
    }); };
```

Here is the test:

```
describe('publishMessage', function() {
  describe('Success', function() {
    it('should return the messageId', function(done) {
      var publishMessage = index.__get__('publishMessage');
      var promise = sinon.stub().resolves(['1111']);
      var publisher = {
        publish: promise
      };
      var topic = {
        publisher: sinon.stub().returns(publisher)
      };
      var pubsub = {
        topic: sinon.stub().returns(topic)
      };
      assert.equal('1111', publishMessage(pubsub, 'st', 'ds'));
      assert.isTrue(topic.publisher.calledWith());
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

And when I execute the test, the output from the `console.log` shows the resolve value is printed:

```
  publishMessage
    Success
      1) should return the messageId
1111


  0 passing (256ms)
  1 failing

  1) publishMessage
       Success
         should return the messageId:
     AssertionError: expected '1111' to equal {}
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.spec.js:63:14)
```

Comment: There's a couple of potential areas where you might run into problems.  Make sure `index.__get__()` returns the method you expect.  Next, unless your assertion library waits for promises to be resolved, you are comparing a Promise (which is returned by `publishMessage()`) that _eventually_ resolves to a String to a String.  Sinon uses real Promises.  Instead you could do `publishMessage(pubsub, 'st', 'ds').then((result) => { assert.equal(result, '1111'); done(); });`.  Let me know if this helps and I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few potential problem areas that I noticed.

First, I don't see where `index` is defined, so I can't confirm whether or not the function you expect is being returned from `index.__get__('publishMessage');`.  You can confirm that the right function is returned by visually inspecting the result of

```
publishMessage.toString();
```

The other problem I see (and more likely the cause of your problem) is that you are returning a Promise from `publishMessage()`, but comparing the result of a call to that function to the value to which the Promise will eventually resolve.  In other words, your comparing a Promise to a String.  Unless your assertion library waits for the Promise to resolve before checking the result (similar to Jasmine), you are comparing a String to a Promise.  To remedy this, simply wait for the Promise to resolve:

```
it('should return the messageId', function(done) {
    // Set up the test case by defining publishMessage, etc.

    publishMessage(pubsub, 'st', 'ds').then((result) => {
        assert.equal(result, '1111');
        assert.isTrue(topic.publisher.calledWith());

        done();
    }).catch(done);
}
```

Notice I added a `.catch()` on the Promise.  This makes sure that any errors thrown *in* the Promise will show the appropriate error as opposed to just a timed out error.

If you're using a testing framework like Mocha or Karma/Jasmine, you can improve this a little more by directly returning the Promise instead of using `done()`.  In my experience, returning the Promise results in much better stack traces and more helpful and accurate error messages when trying to debug a test case that uses Promises.  As an example:

```
it('should return the messageId', function() {
    // Set up the test case by defining publishMessage, etc.

    return publishMessage(pubsub, 'st', 'ds').then((result) => {
        assert.equal(result, '1111');
        assert.isTrue(topic.publisher.calledWith());
    });
}
```

Notice that I don't accept an argument in the test case anymore.  In Mocha and Karma, this is how the framework determines how to treat the test case.

Answer (score 2):

You don't wait for your promise to be resolved.

Try

```
publishMessage(pubsub, 'st', 'ds').then(result => {
  assert.equal('1111', result);
  assert.isTrue(topic.publisher.calledWith());
  done();
}
```